Performant alternative to scaling a CIImage / PixelBuffer
I’m building a camera app where I am applying real time effects to the view finder. One of those effects is a variable blur, so to improve performance I am scaling down the input image using CIFilter.lanczosScaleTransform(). This works fine and runs at 30FPS, but when running the metal profiler I can see that the scaling transforms use a lot of GPU time, almost as much as the variable blur. Is there a more efficient way to do this?
The simplified chain is like this:

Scale down viewFinder CVPixelBuffer (CIFilter.lanczosScaleTransform)
Scale up depthMap CVPixelBuffer to match viewFinder size (CIFilter.lanczosScaleTransform)
Create CIImages from both
CVPixelBuffers Apply VariableDepthBlur (CIFilter.maskedVariableBlur)
Scale up final image to metal view size
(CIFilter.lanczosScaleTransform)
Render CIImage to a MTKView using
CIRenderDestination

From some research, I wonder if scaling the CVPixelBuffer using the accelerate framework would be faster? Also, Instead of scaling the final image, perhaps I could offload this to the metal view?
Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Have you tried using ciImage.transformed(by: affineTransform) instead of Lanczos? This should be the most performant transformation method but doesn't offer the same quality as Lanczos. However, if you apply a blur anyway, it should be totally fine to use.

Thanks I'll give it a try and see if it improves performance!

lanczos is overkill. learn about image pyramids. a simple (gaussian) blur with 3x3 kernel, followed by decimation, is plenty fast.

I'll look into it thanks.

@FrankRupprecht this helped reduce both CPU and GPU usage, however it didn't seem to have much impact when upscaling vs downscaling, might you know why?

@AlexFox You mean that upscaling with transform is as expensive as with Lanczos? I don't know. Upscaling is more expensive in general (more pixels need to be produced). And Apple's Lanczos implementation should be very efficient already.
